# Rails - I need a checkbox to change a field in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, checkbox

I know I have done this before, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I have a table with a "called" field in it. I need to use a checkbox to update the db and check if "called" is "true" or not. Doesn't need to be AJAX, just needs to update the field.

table: rsvp
field: called

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach without ajax could be using a checkbox inside a form and submitting the form with the checkbox javascript onclick event.

*Example:*

---

**View**:

```
<% form_for @rsvp, :id => "rsvp" do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :called, :onclick => "$('#rsvp').submit()" %>
<% end %>
```

this if you are using JQuery... with prototype the onclick string will be:

```
$('rsvp').submit()
```

**Controller**:

```
@rsvp = Rsvp.find(params[:id])
if @rsvp.update_attributes(params[:rsvp])
  # success
else 
  # fail
end
```

---

Reference:

[check box](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001612)

Answer (score 2):

In view:

```
<% form_for :rsvp, :url => {:controller => "rsvp", :action => "update"} do |f| %>
   <%= f.check_box :called %>
   <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

In rsvp controller, update method:

```
@RSVPobject.updateAttribute(:called, params[:rsvp][:called])
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking to update the field just by clicking the checkbox, not submitting a form. Any other ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do this just by clicking the checkbox, you need to go the Ajax road.
Try using an "observe_field" in your view.

```
<%= observe_field ":called",
                    :frequency  => 0.25,
                    :update     => 'feedback_to_user',
                    :url        => {:action => :mark_as_called},
                    :with       => 'called',
                    :on         => 'click' %>
```

All the details [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001654).

Don't forget to adjust your routes so that the "mark_as_called" action can be found.

Comment: I wouldn't specify the frequency since that means it would use polling. Instead omit that option or specify 0, and the code will use the event observer instead.