# Rails: Checkbox to change the value of a variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a basic to do type app and I am trying to change the variable `completed` for an `item` to the current date/time when I click a checkbox.  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978525/rails-i-need-a-checkbox-to-change-a-field-in-the-db), which has led me to the following code structure:

My `lists#show`, on which `items` are created, checked off (updated), edited, and deleted:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 70px"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1 container">
  <div class="md-well">
    <h1 class="text-center"><%= @list.name %></h1>
    <% if @items.count == 0 %>
      <h4 class="text-center">You don't have any items on this list yet! Want to add some?<h4>
    <% elsif @items.count == 1 %>
      <h4 class="text-center">Only <%= @items.count %> Item To Go!</h4>
    <% else %>
      <h4 class="text-center">You Have <%= @items.count %> Items To Go!</h4>
    <% end %>

    <%= render 'items/form' %>

    <% @items.each do |item|%>
      <p>
       <%= form_for [@list, item], class: "inline-block", id: 'item<%= item.id %>' do |f| %>
         <%= f.check_box :completed, :onclick => "$this.parent.submit()" %>
       <% end %>
        <%= item.name %>
        ( <%= link_to "Delete", list_item_path(@list, item), method: :delete %> )
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <div class="text-center">
      <%= link_to "Back to My Lists", lists_path %>
    </div> <!-- text-center -->

  </div> <!-- well -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

Here is my `update` method in my `items_controller` (which I believe has jurisdiction instead of the `lists_controller` even though it is the `lists#show` page because it is an `item` being updated:

```
  def update
    @list = List.friendly.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.find(params[:id])

    @item.name = params[:item][:name]
    @item.delegated_to = params[:item][:delegated_to]
    @item.days_til_expire = params[:item][:days_til_expire]
    @item.completed = params[:item][:completed]
    @item.user = current_user

    if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
      @item.completed = Time.now
    end

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "List was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @list
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving list. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Here is what is currently appearing:

[image: <code>lists#show</code> view]

And here are the two problems I'm having:

1. LESS IMPORTANT PROBLEM: The checkboxes should be displayed inline with the list items but aren't. My class `inline-block` simply makes links to this in the `application.scss` file:

   .inline-block {
     display: inline-block !important;
   }
2. MORE IMPORTANT PROBLEM: Even after the checkbox is clicked, the value for `completed` remains `nil` as per my console:

   [6] pry(main)> Item.where(name: "Feed Dexter")
     Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."name" = ?  [["name", "Feed Dexter"]]
   => [#]

Any ideas how to make this functional?

Comment: Why do you have a `update_attributes` followed by a `save` in the same flow of action?

Comment: The `update_attributes` is a recent addition (while trying to implement the checkbox functionality) and the `save` was working prior to this change. The lack of functionality persists when both are combined under the `update_attributes`, removing the `save`.  Should they be combined anyway?

Comment: `id: "item"` - if every form has the same id... html will be confused as to *which* form to submit when you do this: `"$('#item').submit()"` - it will pick the first one out of however many are on the page to submit. Make sure you give each form a unique id eg try: `id: "item<%= item.id %>"`  `"$('#item<%= item.id %>').submit()"` (note, not tested it will probably have bugs that you can fix with google). Though possibly you could do better with something like `"$this.parent.submit()"` or similar

Comment: `update_attributes` does the same thing as `save`. Only in the first you pass an hash, and in the second you call the method from an object. So basically, it is the same thing. You can remove the `update_attributes` call and just use `save`.

Comment: @MurifoX, thanks for the clarification.  So updated.

Comment: @TarynEast, as expected, it's throwing up all kinds of crazy errors. Is there any other way to skin this particular cat?

Comment: as expected? :) This is a javascript bug you're now looking at... have a google for the right way of doing that (my javascript knowledge is not good enough that I can do it without googling the right way). look up "jquery this" "jquery parent" and "jquery submit" and you'll probably figure out the right way.

Comment: @TarynEast, well you said "it will probably have bugs", and I don't speak javascript very well, so this could take some time. *crosses fingers and hopes javascript ninja falls from the sky*

Comment: haha fair enough :D